# CMake does not find a specific boost library (boost_random)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, installation

I know that there are already similar questions with good solutions; However, none of those solutions helped to resolve my problem. I am trying to build a library for my research experiments. This library requires Boost 1.48 as one of its prerequisites. I had built this library on my personal Ubuntu on a server and everything was fine. I used following commands to install required boost libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options1.48-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.48-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.48-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-random1.48-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-thread1.48-dev
```

Now I have to install this library on another server. I am not an administrator on this one; hence I do not have enough privileges to install packages or use `sudo`. So I downloaded boost 1.48 from its website and extracted it to a local place. Then I set the environment variables to address the boost local directory.

```
export BOOST_ROOT= <"boost extracted directory">
export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=<"boost extracted directory/lib">
```

This time CMake finds all boost libraries except `boost_random`.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1138 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.48.0

  Boost include path: /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_random

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost. Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I will highly appreciate if you can help me to resolve this problem.

**Note:** the report of `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/ -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/libs/ -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/boost/ .. > out6.txt` is as follow:

```
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:481 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:483 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:485 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:487 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:489 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:491 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:543 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:545 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:547 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/boost/
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:549 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/libs/
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:551 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:620 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:622 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/boost/;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0//include;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:624 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:644 ] location of version.hpp: /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:668 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.48.0
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc44
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:754 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:797 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:799 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:847 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/libs/;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0//lib;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0//stage/lib;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/lib;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/../lib;/home/ME/Research/BOOST/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-gcc44-mt-1_48;boost_program_options-gcc44-mt;boost_program_options-mt-1_48;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-gcc44-mt-d-1_48;boost_program_options-gcc44-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d-1_48;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc44-mt-1_48;boost_system-gcc44-mt;boost_system-mt-1_48;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc44-mt-d-1_48;boost_system-gcc44-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_48;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc44-mt-1_48;boost_filesystem-gcc44-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_48;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc44-mt-d-1_48;boost_filesystem-gcc44-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_48;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for RANDOM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_random-gcc44-mt-1_48;boost_random-gcc44-mt;boost_random-mt-1_48;boost_random-mt;boost_random
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for RANDOM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_random-gcc44-mt-d-1_48;boost_random-gcc44-mt-d;boost_random-mt-d-1_48;boost_random-mt-d;boost_random-mt;boost_random
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:957 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc44-mt-1_48;boost_thread-gcc44-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_48;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc44-mt-d-1_48;boost_thread-gcc44-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_48;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1044 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ME/Research/CURRENNT/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: From shell search if you have `boost_random` for example with `locate boost_random`.  In an installation by sudo you can find in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_random.a`... in a user one you should search for it.

Comment: I downloaded the standard boost library from `boost.org`. The random library actually exists in the `boost_1_48_0/libs` and its includes are in `boost_1_48_0/boost/`. Also why `cmake` can find other boost libraries such as `boost_thread` or `boost_filesystem` but it has problem finding `boost_random`?

Comment: Have you actually built the required boost libraries?  Your question seems to indicate that you haven't - i.e. that you've just downloaded and extracted the Boost sources.  If you *have* built Boost.Random, what's the full path (including filename) of the compiled library?  It shouldn't be `boost_1_48_0/libs` - that should contain the source files, docs, examples, etc.

Comment: @Fraser Yes, you are right. I hadn't built the boost libraries. That had been the problem. So, I built the required libraries using  `booststrap.sh`; and now problem is solved. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -5):

I am not sure if this will help, but if CMake uses a makefile concept, then this is what I had to add to my makefile to compile boost successfully (but I use Gnu Make, so again, not sure if this will help):

`LDLIBS := -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`

I will guess you need to add something like `-lboost_random` ?

Comment: I'm afraid CMake syntax is quite different - this answer doesn't really help.